# How to delete the startup file itself test.exe?

Tags: nsis

After running the .exe file, I need to delete the file so that it no longer exists.
I have a script that I create a file to run, but how to delete it after launch?

```
Outfile test.exe
Requestexecutionlevel user
Setcompressor LZMA
Page instfiles

Section
;Not a good idea to hardcode the destination like this, 
;normally you would use a directory page so the user can choose
SetOutPath "c:\SaveToThisFolder"

;Take thefile.txt from the system you compile on and output it on the end users system 
;into the directory specified by the SetOutPath call
File "thefile.txt"
Sectionend
```

How to delete file test.exe after run?

Comment: It is not normal for a Sfx to delete itself and the user could just make a copy before running it.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard for a Windows process to delete itself and NSIS does not really support it but you can try the [SelfDel plug-in](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/SelfDel_plug-in)